# Cloning a input HTML element with a value and putting it back in the DOM if the user cancels overwriting the current input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently trying to make a modal that uses a file input for storing a csv in the state. The issue I am trying to get around is that if an input is selected but the user misclicks on the "choose file" and presses cancel, the file they originally selected is no longer there.

Right now, with the current code below, I am cloning the input element if the user selects a .csv. Then, if the user presses choose file and then presses cancel, the input is appended with the cloned element that contains the original value. Now, when doing so the first time the input element shows up as its supposed to. However, if I do it for a second time in row, the onclick function does not fire and the input goes back to "No file chosen"

```
var NameClone ={};

handleCurrentUpload = (e) => {
    var fileElement = e.target;
    if (fileElement.value == "") {
        this.FileDomObject(fileElement);
    }

FileDomObject = (fileElement) => {
    var fileChange = document.getElementById(`TE-file`)
    fileChange.parentNode.appendChild(NameClone[fileElement.id]);
    fileChange.parentNode.removeChild(fileChange);
}

handleFileUpload = (e) => {
var fileElement = e.target;
    if (fileElement.value != ""){
     NameClone[fileElement.id] = fileElement.cloneNode(true);
    } 
}

<input
    disabled={this.state.loading}
    id={`TE-file`}
    className={showRequired(checkRequired, this.state, "FileName") 
    || FileMessage ? "file-input req" : "file-input"}
    data-allowed-file-extensions="csv"
    type="file"
    accept=".csv"
    onChange={e => {this.handleCurrentUpload(e)}}
    onClick={e => {this.handleFileUpload(e)}}
/>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with JSFiddle?

Comment: Some of the code in here I grabbed from a jsfiddle example

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't mean your question has to do with JSFiddle

Comment: @Scott Marcus It's gone sir